# Display total weight of cart in the magento header

Tags: magento

I have only simple products that I want to show total weight of cart in the header section after the "My Cart" link.

Could anybody help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$weight = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $weight += ($item->getWeight() * $item->getQty()) ;
}

echo $weight;
```

A better way:

```
$weight = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
              ->getQuote()
              ->getShippingAddress()
              ->getWeight();
```

Comment: thank you @chapagain, I will try and let you know the result.

Comment: if you put more than one same product to cart, the code that you gave me above doesn't work. It is always displaying one products weight, not multiplying with product quantity. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Edited the answer. Now it should work for multiple qty for a single product. Please reply if this does work or not.

Comment: Just a note: there is a problem with this method if you have Configurable or Bundle products in the cart, which consist also of Simple products. In this case you will add the weight of Configurable product plus weight of Simple product which will result of wrong total weight (double), since you should only calculate weight of simple products.

Comment: try use `getPackageWeight()`

Comment: @MukeshChapagain I want to add packaging charges based on cart total weight, conditions -> http://pasted.co/e9db4cfc How can add using PHP code or any other way.

Comment: @MukeshChapagain I need to display cart weight in Ajax cart, like click and view cart, where i can paste the above code.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$weight = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight();
```

Comment: Works even without a shipping_address

Comment: I need to display cart weight in Ajax cart, like click and view cart, where i can paste the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to the minicart.phtml just under Total price,

```
<span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Weight')?>: </span>
<?php echo $_quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote(); echo $_weight = $_quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight();?>
```

Thanks for the post here!

Comment: I need to display cart weight in Ajax cart, like click and view cart, where i can paste the above code.